# Wordpress Header Width (Genesis, Foodie Pro)

Tags: css, wordpress

http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/

Having issues getting the header to look the way I want it to. I'd like the section in blue to be full width (as it currently is) but I want the actual header (the logo and navigation) to be the same width as the rest of the content (1040px) - hope this makes sense.

I was told to at a wrap around the "site-header" but I am new to Wordpress and am not sure how to do this.

Not sure what coding I need to provide, but here's some to start:

```css
/*
Site Header
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


.foodie-pro .site-header {
 background-color: #0099CC !important;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.genesis-header {
 background-color: #000000 !important;
}

.foodie-pro .site-header {

 background-position: left;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.title-area {
 width: 450px;
}

.header-image .title-area {
 padding: 0;
}

.title-area h1 {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.title-area p {
 margin: 0;
}

/* Full width header, no widgets */

.header-full-width .title-area,
.header-full-width .site-title {
 width: 100%;
}

.header-image .site-description,
.header-image .site-title a {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
}

/* Logo, hide text */

.header-image .site-header {
 background-size: 450px 177px !important;
}

.header-image .site-title a {
 float: none;
 min-height: 177px;
 width: 450px;
}

/*
Site Navigation
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Main Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
 display: inline-block;
}

.genesis-nav-menu {
 margin-top: -118px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu:before {
 content: "BROWSE RECIPES:";
 color: #f68364;
 font-size: 11.5px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu {
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 11.5px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 8px;
 color: #636367;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 transition: all 0s ease !important;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a:hover {
 color: #6dbea2;
}

li#menu-item-150 a {
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 3px;
 color: #f68364;
}

.menu-item:last-child a {
 padding-right: 0px;
}


li#menu-item-119:after, li#menu-item-120:after, li#menu-item-121:after {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 content: "/";
 color: #b9b9b9;
}

/* Sub Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.menu-primary li{
 position: relative;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu  {
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #7b7c80;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 z-index: 2000;
 left: -9999px;
 width: 100px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a {
 width: 100px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #7b7c80;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #f78f73;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader"><div class="wrap"><div class="title-area"><h1 class="site-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/">Living the Lighter Life</a></h1><p class="site-description" itemprop="description">Eat Clean. Train Hard. Live Lighter.</p></div></div></header><h2 class="screen-reader-text">Main navigation</h2><nav class="nav-primary" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="genesis-nav-primary" aria-label="Main navigation"><div class="wrap"><ul id="menu-main" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary"><li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-119"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breakfast</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-151" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-151"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/recipes/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Recipes</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-120"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Lunch</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-156" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-156"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/recipes-new__trashed-2/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Recipes NEW</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-121"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dinner</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-160"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Coming Soon</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-148"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Other</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Desserts</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Snacks</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-123"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sides</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-125" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-125"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Beverages</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-150"><a itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">•</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-25"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Nutrition &#038; Fitness</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-126"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Philosophy</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Workouts</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is wrap your header and nav in a `<div>` with the same styling. Or as another option, I would probably just put your navigation insider your header though, so that the structure is something like this:

```
<header>
    <div class="logo__container">Stuff</div>
    <nav>Navigation Stuff</nav>
</header>
```

and then just have your header styled in the same way as your content container:

```
.header {
    width: 1040px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: Where do I go to wrap it? I'm not sure where to find the code to wrap.

Comment: Well, that's hard to say without seeing your project...is the code you pasted in your question all in one place...? Or is it somewhere else, split up?

Comment: My project is at livingthelighterlife.com

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with Wordpress so not sure which page to go into to add that wrap. I understand how the wrap works, and even where it needs to go, just not how to get there - if that makes sense.

Comment: It's honestly going to be very hard for me to tell you where to go without seeing your file structure. Where have you written the code for the current header? I would probably go there?

Comment: I've been messing around with it a little bit and made some progress. If you go now, you see I have the wrap section black for easy visibility right now. The "link" that should appear over the logo background is in the correct location (very left of the black bar) and the navigation is in the correct spot (height will be adjusted later). The only thing I can fix is getting the uploaded header to land in the black area. Ideas?

Comment: well, your nav and menu-toggle are outside the header; you should really put them inside so you can wrap them all up in one tidy container if you want them all inside one bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the following to achieve what you want:

```
.site-header{
 max-width: 1040px;
}

#menu-main{
 max-width: 1040px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-right: 2em;
}
```

And to fix the hamburger menu on small devices change the `top` property value to `35px;`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1039px){
 button#responsive-menu-button {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px; /*Changed this*/
    right: 5%;
 }
}
```